# How do I declare a point as one of an objects arguements?

Tags: java

I am asked to create a robot object and then move it around and keep track of it
using java's awt.point class. I believe I might be using this point class completely wrong and need your help. Thank You! Here is the main and the class code. //Main - Getting error when trying to create point! The class code starts at the import. Just wondering if I am doing the constructor with the private point object as an instance variable. Thanks for all the feedback!

```
public class RobotDirections
{

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Robot Craig = new Robot((0,0), 1) ;
    }
}
import java.awt.Point ;
public class Robot
{
    private int directionFacing ;
    private Point robot = new Point() ;
    //North East South West
    private String N_E_S_W_ ;
    int X = 0 ;
    int Y = 0 ;

    public Robot(Point robot , int directionFacing){
        this.directionFacing = 1 ;
        this.robot = robot ;
     }

    public void turnLeft(){
        if(directionFacing == 1 ){
            directionFacing = 5 ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 2 ){
        directionFacing = 2 ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 3 ){
        directionFacing = 3 ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 4 ){
        directionFacing = 4 ;
    }
    directionFacing-- ; 
}

public void turnRight(){
    if(directionFacing == 4 ){
        directionFacing = 0 ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 1 ){
        directionFacing = 1 ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 2 ){
        directionFacing = 2 ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 3 ){
        directionFacing = 3 ;
    }
    directionFacing++ ;
}

public void move(){
    if(directionFacing == 1){
         robot.setLocation(X, Y++) ; 
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 2){
        robot.setLocation(X, Y) ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 3){
        robot.setLocation(X, Y--) ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 4){
        robot.setLocation(--X,Y) ;
    }
}

public Point getLocation(){
    return robot ;
}

public String getDirection(){
    if(directionFacing == 1){
        N_E_S_W_ = "N" ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 2){
        N_E_S_W_ = "E" ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 3){
        N_E_S_W_ = "S" ;
    }
    else if(directionFacing == 4){
        N_E_S_W_ = "W" ;
    }
    return N_E_S_W_  ;    
} 
}
```

Comment: Please take the site [tour] - note that "opinion polls" like this aren't permitted. Please [edit] to make this answerable with facts, references, etc.

Comment: Please re-open this question

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Point` is part of Java's Abstract Window Toolki and intended for GUI programming. Thus you are misusing it which is discouraged, but it will work.
WHy don't create your own robot position class?

Some other observations: You can shorten a lot of your methods when you reassign the identical value to a variable as it has already. E.g.

```
public void turnLeft(){
    if (directionFacing == 1) {
        directionFacing = 5;
    }
    directionFacing--; 
}
```